# Variables not setting after posting from html form

Tags: php, html, forms

I am practicing sending data from a form and echoing that data in a different php script. However, my input is not being posted to the php script that i am pointing my form to.

Hub.php

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hub</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action = "test.php" method = "post">
    <input type ="radio" value ="assignment_2" name ="choice" >Assignment 2</br>
    <input type ="submit" >
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

test.php

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<?php
    echo $_POST["choice"];
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

After I click the submit button, I am redirected to the test.php page, but it says  "Undefined index: choice". I have looked at all the other posts regarding this matter, but none of the answers seem to work for me. Can someone please let me know what i am doing wrong? I am new to php and working with form data so any help will be appreciated.

Thank You.

Okay, so after trying various things suggested by @Alfredo EM, the get method is working and gives me the following output when i run `var_dump($_GET);`

```
array(2) { ["choice"]=> string(12) "assignment_2" ["textfield"]=> string(7) "my text" }
```

The post method is still not working.

Comment: the radio button was `checked` before submitting the form presumably?

Comment: @RamRaider Yes it was

Comment: add another input type=text for example and make a var_dump($_POST) to check if the data is sending

Comment: @AlfredoEM I did what you said and put some text in the text field as well. this is what i get  `array(0) { }`

Comment: @H.Qureshi you put a value on the input=text name attribute? If it does not work try changing the method to form method=get and var_dump($_GET)

Comment: @AlfredoEM Yes this is how my input is ` <input type="text" name="textfield">`

Comment: I've tested your code on Chrome, Firefox, and IE and they both work. What browser are you using? What php server are you using? The only thing I can see a little off with your code is the spaces around your `=`s

Comment: @AlfredoEM Oh my god! the get works, and I am getting the values now! but the post isn't working.

Comment: @Hollings I am using Chrome. as i mentioned in an earlier comment, the get method works, but the post method doesn't.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9752882/php-forms-get-working-but-post-not - "The one site that did not work I had set the URL encoding to always remove "www". My solution was to enforce the URL to always add "www" and the issue was gone." Could this be the problem? Is your .htaccess redirecting you?

Comment: @Hollings I am running it on localhost and i am not being redirected to a different page. It takes me to the correct page, but doesn't post anything.

Comment: Try to remove spaces between `=` i.e `<form method="POST">` and make `post` in uppercase i.e `POST`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do remember I have saw this issue before, have a look this if you are testing the scripts on your localhost. Hope this can help you.

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207255485-No-POST-values-caught

Comment: This was the main issue all along. Thank you! it turns out that since i was using phpStorm and testing on their apache server, it was blocking my post requests. i fixed it by using XAMPP's apache server instead. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Radio buttons don't send Post data if they aren't checked, so you'll get an `Undefined index` error if you try to access it. You can use this code to test if it is checked or not:

```
if(isset($_POST["choice"])){
    echo $_POST["choice"];  
} else{
    echo "Not checked";
}
```

Comment: I did that and it says not checked. I even checked it inside the HTML so it starts off checked but it still says not checked.

Answer (score 0):

You should verify radio button checked before submitting.

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="test.php">
  <input type="radio" name="choice" value="assignment_2"/>Assignment 2</br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  if (isset($_POST['choice'])) {
    $choice = $_POST['choice'];
    echo $choice;
  } else {
    echo 'No Data selected';
  }
}
```